# Laravel can only upload image of few KB with react-native

Tags: laravel, react-native, amazon-s3

So I have made an image uploader via react-native, that goes to laravel and then to Amazon S3. It does work, but I can only upload an image of x kb. Everything that is x mb I cant upload.

I am getting this error as response:

```
{"message":"The img url failed to upload.","errors":{"img_url":["The img url failed to upload."]}}
```

This is my laravel code:

```
public function CreateExercise(CreateExerciseRequest $request){


        if ($request->hasFile('img_url')){
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('images', $request->img_url);
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

            return $path;
        }
    }
```

this is my validation class:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'string|unique:exercises|required',
            'description' => 'string|required',
            'img_url' => 'image|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:4096',
            'video_url' => 'file|mimetypes:video/mp4|nullable'
        ];
    }
```

And this is how i upload it from react native:

```
newExercise.name = "bench"
        newExercise.description = "iets"
        newExercise.img_url = image
        let result = newExercise.img_url.uri.split(/[.;+_]/).pop();
        const newImageUri =  "file:///" + imageUri.split("file:/").join("");
        console.log(newImageUri)

        form.append('name', newExercise.name)
        form.append('description', newExercise.description)

        form.append('img_url', {
            uri: newImageUri,
            name: 'eentest.'+result,
            type: mime.getType(newImageUri)
        })
        const token = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken'))
        return await fetch(defaultUrl + '/exercise/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                // 'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=" + Math.random().toString().substr(2),
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            body: form
        })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e)
            })
```

I've tried to increase the `post_max_size` in my `php.ini` did not work.

Do you guys know what I could do?

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of data for the image do you upload - base64 or BLOB?

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel it's not base64 so I guess it's a BLOB

Comment: `newImageUri`  is a reference to image data in device memory, it does not contain actually image binary data

Comment: You need to fetch BLOB data from `newImageUri` and upload those data